# Twitter and facebook button image change?

Tags: facebook, button, twitter, authentication, logout

I am attempting to log a user into facebook and twitter through my apps, then once logged in I would like the images in my drop down menu to change to logout images. The issue that I'm having is that my facebook button does not change when it is clicked. it only changes when I click the log out of twitter button that initiates a session_destroy. how can I fix this.

Twitter button:

```
<li><?php if(isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['status']== 'verified'): ?>
<a href="index.php?reset=2"></i><img src="images/twitter_logo2.png" width="35" height="35"      
/><ul id="dropdownMenuText">Logout:</ul></a>

<?php else: ?>
<a href="process.php"><img src="images/sign-in-with-twitter-l.png" width="151" height="24"     
border="0" /></a></li>

<?php endif ?>
```

facebook button:

```
<li> 
<?php if ($user): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>"><img src="images/logo_facebook.png" width="35"     
height="35" /><ul id="dropdownMenuText">Logout:</ul></a>
<?php else: ?>
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>"><img src="images/facebook_signing2.png" width="151"      
height="24"border="0" /></a><?php endif ?>
</li>
```

here is where my twitter button goes:

```
if($_GET["reset"]==2)
{
session_destroy();
header('Location: ./index.php');
}
```